# Post-hoc Chi Square Test for Pairwise Comparison of 3 Groups

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, stata, fishers-exact-test

I am trying to do something that in my mind is probably simple and I'm probably just blanking on it.  I am using Stata to compare 3 groups on a categorical variable.  So, as an example, I would be comparing the groups of the variable 'race' (Black, Latino, White) across the categorical variable of education (less than high school, hs/some college, college graduate).  So the question that I am asking is: Do Black people, Latino people, and White people differ significantly in their levels of education *and* between which groups are there significant differences?  I ran a chi square test (actually Fisher's exact test because of some empty cells) and now know that there are significant differences among the groups.  Now, how do I check to see what the pairwise differences are (i.e., Black vs. Latino, Latino vs. White, Black vs. White)?  Is there a post-hoc test for this?  Or do I need to recode the variables to be more conducive to pairwise testing?  Or should I instead go with a multinomial logistic regression?  Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Why would empty cells make you use Fisher's exact test?

Comment: I see now that that was probably unnecessary.  I thought that having observed values lower than 5 necessitated using Fisher's exact test.  But it is actually expected values of less than 5.